# Check all checkboxes after page load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How to select all checkboxes while click on a checkbox after page load.

my html code is,

```
 <table id="dealer_select_list" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th><input id="selectall" type="checkbox">Select All</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="Dlist_cont">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Remaining checkboxes are displayed after a button click. And the code is,

```
 $list .= "<td><input id='checkBox' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' value='{$dl['id']}'></td>";
```

my jquery code is,

```
  $('#selectall').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
      } else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
   });
```

This code is not working because I think the checkboxes are appearing after page load. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Show your HTML ?

Comment: I added html code above

Comment: You take your code in $(document).ready(funtion(){})?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selectall').click(function () {
  
     $(":checkbox",$("#Dlist_cont"))
      .prop("checked",this.checked? "checked":"");
    
  });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dealer_select_list" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th><input id="selectall" type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select All</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="Dlist_cont">
<tr><td>1</td><td>C1</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>C2</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append your dynamic checkbox after `#selectall` click like below example. I add extra tr to your html to append this. You can see result on snippet.

```js
 var $list = "<td><input id='checkBox' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' value='{$dl['id']}'>New one</td>";
$('#selectall').click(function () {

    if (this.checked) {
    $("#dealer_select_list #test").html('').append($list);
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
      } else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dealer_select_list" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th><input id="selectall" type="checkbox">Select All</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id='test'><tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="Dlist_cont">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```